# Can't getId() in nested setOnClickListener

Tags: android, onclick, popup

I have a button, when I click it, a popup window shows which contains 4 buttons.
According to which button user clicked in popup window, the popup trigger button will update itself. But I face a problem that cant getId() in the code below.

```
public void pressCell(View view) {

    final ImageButton popup = (ImageButton) findViewById(view.getId());

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

    popupView.findViewById(popupView.getId()).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button1:
                        popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num1);
                    case R.id.button2:
                        popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num2);
                    case R.id.button3:
                        popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num3);
                    case R.id.button4:
                        popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num4);

                    }
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }

            });

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(findViewById(view.getId()), -120, -2
            * findViewById(view.getId()).getHeight());

}
```

pressCell is the onCLick function of the trigger button:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cell1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="pressCell"
            android:src="@drawable/num3" />
```

can anyone tell me whats the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: use popup.setOnClickListener for setting onClickLinstener for multiple views and also add break in switch case

Comment: Is there any difference between using setOnClickListener and using android:onclick? Since I have many trigger buttons, so I really dont want to set Listener on each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get ImageButton's reference should be use;

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)popupView.findViewById(R.id.cell1);
```

In your code setOnClickLİstener method you get popupView reference;

```
popupView.findViewById(popupView.getId()).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {  // clicked view popupView.
                switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num1);
                case R.id.button2:
                    popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num2);
                case R.id.button3:
                    popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num3);
                case R.id.button4:
                    popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.num4);

                }
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }

        });
```

Comment: The reason I choose android:onClick is I have many of these trigger buttons. I dont want to set lisenter on each of them. If I do as you said, I should find cell1 to celln, its a lot of work. Actually, this part works well. The problem is in this line: popupView.findViewById(popupView.getId()).setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the onClickListener, you are doing this :

```
 popupView.findViewById(popupView.getId()).setOnClickListener
```

Shouldn't you pass `view.getId` to the findViewById method instead ?

Comment: Because I think I should getId from current popup window view, but not the same with the view contains the trigger button. Right?